# Read data in formatted tables in excel javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, alasql, sheetjs

I need to read data from an excel file. In the excel file, there are formatted tables which contains the data I need to retrieve. Is there an API available to do this?

Currently, I'm using to read data in Excel is the ALASQL wherein it returns a JSON object of the data in the excel and does not detect formatted tables. I also found SheetJS which also returns JSON object, CSV format and other formats of the excel file that reads the excel file row by row.

Sample Excel file needs to be read in Javascript. It should be able to detect the formatted tables and get the data in the tables

See the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of excel with nodeJS work as well but using javascript for excel works don't scale very well at all.

From my experience the best tool available for such a job is `Aspose.Cells for Javascript via Java` https://products.aspose.com/cells/javascript especially if you are working in an enterprise - it's a very solid solution and best one available. The speed might be much faster on .NET based though.

Another way of doing it is creating an xml parser because `xlsx` file is pretty much just a compressed version of an xml file - it'll be very much an overkill but it depends on what kind of application you are trying to create.

As of open source libraries, I have not seen anything that does anything as sophisticated as reading table formats.